# Lyx refuses to work with images of various formats; Error: Cannot convert file

Tags: graphics, lyx, linux

I am simply trying to insert pictures into the document; all I get is:

> Error: Cannot convert file
>
> No information for converting png format files to eps. Define a
>   converter in the preferences.

And as god is my witness I have tried. I attempted modyfying 'Tools -> Preferences -> File Handling -> Converters' but I am confused as of what exactly is expected. Is there any special requirements for images in Lyx?

The environment is Arch of version bleeding edge and Lyx 2.3.1.

Full error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/lyx/scripts/convertDefault.py", line 38, in <module>
    output = output.decode()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
Systemcall.cpp (294): Systemcall: 'python -tt "/usr/share/lyx/scripts/convertDefault.py" png "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.uwjpEexWrZGG/lyx_tmpbuf0/0_home_sebastian_Temp_Felis_silvestris_silvestris_small_gradual_decrease_of_quality.png" eps "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.uwjpEexWrZGG/lyx_tmpbuf0/0_home_sebastian_Temp_Felis_silvestris_silvestris_small_gradual_decrease_of_quality.eps"' finished with exit code 1
Error: Cannot convert file
----------------------------------------
No information for converting png format files to eps.
Define a converter in the preferences.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./assignment1.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5

Systemcall.cpp (294): Systemcall: 'latex "assignment1.tex"' finished with exit code 1
```

Any help much appreciated, I don't want to go back to LO only because of this.

Comment: Sure that you need convert png to eps files? Unlike long time ago, actually is not necessary in most cases. You can produce a PDF output directly with pdflatex using  png, jpg and pdf images without any conversion, whereas eps images cannot be used with that compiler (they are converted first to pdf images).

Comment: I don't think I have to, nor should I, nor I want to. The above error is produced when I try to 'View DVI' of a document with a picture in it. I don't insist on converting it to EPS, Lyx does. I do not know how to prevent the conversion taking place or how to do it any other way :/

Comment: That is the key point. When you ask for a DVI, **you force** to LyX  (to LaTeX) to use *only* eps images, but why the hell you want the output in the old (and mostly unknown) DVI format ? With "View  [PDF(pdflatex)] you will use the PNG directly without problems and the ouput is the well-know PDF format that anyone can open without problems.

Comment: 'View DVI' is the only available option. Glad we are able to come up with some 'key points' means we are getting somewhere.

Comment: Thank you @Fran you have helped me to solve this. It turns out Lyx were unable to detect the pdf viewer I had installed. After installation of such (mupdf) the option to 'View PDF (pdflatex)' this and other options became present and I am able to render resulting pdf file via 'View' menu. Thanks again man I was banging my head against the wall here. Guess that's what happens when you don't understand the tools too well yet you still trying to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use 'DVI' format with documents containing images. Make sure appropriate pdf viewer is present and use 'View PDF(...)' option to render the resulting pdf's.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install `texlive-extra-utils` and `texlive-pstricks` to get pdflatex to work.